# Trigger the event when sort icon ascending or descending is clicked in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Trigger the event when sort icon is clicked in jqgrid;

Like if ascending icon is clicked it should alert like "you clicked on ascending order".

If anyone knows, please help me on this, thanks

```
 $("#list1").jqGrid("GridUnload")
    $("#list1").jqGrid({ url:"./controllers/apGetTestData.php?
 testanzres=1&testsuite="+testsuite+"&testcase="+testcase+"&ch="+ch+"
&fromdate="+fromdate+"&todate="
todate+"&mmss="+mmss, datatype: 'xml', mtype: 'GET', height: 'auto',
    colNames:[ 'RRID', 'Release Tag','Completed   Date','Result',
    'Firmare','DUT','Summary','Remarks'],
    colModel:[

    {name:'idreleaseRequest', index:'idreleaseRequest', width:40},
    {name:'releaseRequestTag', index:'releaseRequestTag'},   
     {name:'DateInfo', index:'Date Info', sortable:true,align:'center'},
    {name:'Result', index:'Result', sortable:false},
    {name:'Firm Ware', index:'Firm Ware', sortable:false},
    {name:'DUT', index:'DUT', sortable:false},        

    {name:'Summary', index:'Summary', sortable:false, align:'left'} ,
     {name:'Remarks', index:'Total Suites', sortable:false}],       
    pager: $('#pager1'), rowNum:6, rowList:[6,12,18,24],

    sortname: 'timeStamp',
    sortorder: "DESC",
    caption:"Test Results : "+ globalData,
    // caption:"Test Results ",
    shrinkToFit:true,
    autowidth: true,
    viewrecords: true,
     rownumbers:true,
     cloneToTop:true,
     hidedlg: true,
     loadonce: true



});
```

Comment: I don't see neither your JS code nor your HTML.

Comment: Hi Regent, i added the code, please tell me any idea regarding this

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid trigger already `jqGridSortCol` event. It has parameters close to parameters of `onSortCol` callback. You can bind your event handler even *before* the `<table>` are converted in jqGrid (after `$("#list1").jqGrid("GridUnload")` for example in). The usage is very simple:

```
$("#list1").on("jqGridSortCol", function (e, sortName, iCol, sortOrder) {
    alert("sortName=" + sortName + "\niCol=" + iCol + "\nsortOrder=" + sortOrder);
});
```

By the way you can stop sorting, if it's required, by returning `"stop"` string from the event handler:

```
$("#list1").on("jqGridSortCol", function (e, sortName, iCol, sortOrder) {
    if (sortName === "columnName") { // test the column name
        alert("Sorry, but sorting by the column is not prohibited");
        return "stop";
    }
});
```

See the corresponding small demo you can find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridSortCol.htm).